# Crontab wont work with `mysqldump: command not found` mac osx

Tags: mysql, shell, cron

I set to cronjob to my local machine

```
❯ crontab -l
* * * * * ~/.scripts/db_back_up.sh
```

```
❯ cat db_back_up.sh
#!/bin/sh

cd /usr/bin/
mysqldump --user=**** --password=**** --host=localhost mydbname > ~/Documents/db_backup/$(date +\%Y_\%m_\%d)_DB_dump.sql 2>&1
```

But it didn't work. with message -  ***mysqldump: command not found***

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but... Is mysqldump installed at that path?

Comment: How can I test it?

Comment: In general terms, when you want to use a program in your computer you install it first and they you invoke it. You don't normally try to guess if it's already there somehow. I'm not a Mac user but I'm positively surer that Apple doesn't bundle MySQL by default in its computers.

Comment: I have no problem to run command in my terminal. 'mysqldump --user=**** --password=**** --host=localhost dbname > filename.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for command path with 'which mysqldump' and add it in your script /path/mysqldump and try again.